# How to phrase a specific question in an idiomatic but explicit way?

Tags: idiomaticity

I’m creating a question pool for students, but I’m not sure my questions will be understood by everyone. The following sentence would introduce a Question-Answer matching practice. Is it explicit enough or does the question need to be a little bit modified?

> Auf welche der folgenden Fragen kann die obige Aussage als eine Antwort gegeben werden?

Students will read a short text (actually, it is an answer of a question), then they will have to pick the best, rational, appropriate answer.

For example:

> An Deutschland grenzen neun Staaten und naturräumlich im Norden die Gewässer der Nord- und Ostsee sowie im Süden das Bergland der Alpen. Es liegt in der gemäßigten Klimazone. ([Source: Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschland))
>
> Auf welche der folgenden Fragen kann die obige Aussage als eine Antwort gegeben werden?
>
> A) Wo liegt Deutschland?
> B) Was kann man in Deutschland essen?
> [...]
> E) Wie viele Einwohner hat Deutschland?

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly you are unsure about? As it stands, the question is at least very close to a proofreading question.

Comment: I wouldn’t ask for that answer with *any* of the three questions you suggest.

Comment: @Jan distractors are actually more than three, here i supplied just for an example

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the title of the question at all. Do you mind rephrasing it?

Comment: The phrase you used is fine. A simpler way of putting it would be _Welche Frage passt zur obigen Antwort?_ Yet i have the impression this question is more or less a translation request?

Comment: And the correct question is: Von was allem wird Deutschland umrandet? Und in welcher Klimazone liegt es?

Comment: assume that premise is" Deutschland liegt in Mitteleuropa.

Comment: Still you are switching subject and object. I *think* you think A) is correct, but it isn't.

Comment: @Bergmann This is not an assumption. Germany *is* located in central Europe.

Comment: @Bergmann, you have enough rep - why don't you just join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum) for a moment?

Comment: I fixed the body of your question, also tried to rephrase your title. (I still do not understand your original title.) Feel free to rollback if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: @Stephie thanks for invitation, will join immediately

Comment: @Bergmann: Dir ist schon klar, dass das hier ein DEUTSCH-Forum ist. Und wenn du, wie in deinem Profil nachzulesen ist, DEUTSCH-Lehrer bist, und in DEUTSCH-Land (nämlich in Düsseldorf) lebst, dann gehe ich davon aus, dass du DEUTSCH auf dem C2-Niveau, also auf dem Niveau eines Muttersprachler spricht. Wenn das alles zutrifft: Warum benutzt du in einem DEUTSCH-Forum eine Fremdsprache (nämlich englisch) um eine Frage über einen Aspekt der DEUTSCHEN Sprache zu stellen?

Comment: @Bergmann: Ich habe nämlich Probleme, deine Frage zu verstehen, und das liegt möglicherweise daran, dass ich Deutsch zwar auf C2-Niveau spreche, English aber nur auf dem Level B2. Und alle anderen Muttersprachler, die sich hier tummeln, täten sich auch leichter wenn die Fragen hier in der Sprache gestellt würden, die das zentrale Thema dieses Forums ist: Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ihre Annahmen halte ich für ambitioniert - mir scheint das Profil des Fragers eher zu einer Lehrkraft für Deutsch als Fremdsprache zu passen, die sich an Migranten, Asylbewerber, o.ä. wendet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast the reason why i compose my question in english is: (1) my PC doesn't support german letters,(2) i'm still assistant teacher,(3) i prefer english as a teaching language,i'm learning deutsch by english. Thanks for visiting my profile but it's actually not updated i mean i'm not living in Düsseldorf anymore,i stayed there only one year that was last year.

Comment: No one says `naturräumlich`. Use `geografisch` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing is fine in principle though slightly awkward. The following suggestions would appear more natural (well, at least to me) and they also take into account that the student's task will be to find a best match instead of identifying the natural answer.

Given the setting ( a multiple-choice problem sheet as part of coursework ), the terse first variant should suffice.

> Wie lautet die passende Frage ?
>
> Zu welcher der folgenden Fragen paßt die obige Antwort am besten ?
>
> Welche der folgenden Fragen könnte (am ehesten) gestellt worden sein ?
>
> Welche der folgenden Fragen wurde vermutlich gestellt ?
>
> Welche der folgenden Fragen wurde gestellt ?

Comment: you gave really nice tips